# Seperate Store for Desktop and Handheld Devices

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, multistore

I need to create separate website for handheld devices and desktop. For that I created a module to make an observer for the event of `controller_action_predispatch`. My config.xml observer snippet is as follows.

```
<global>
  <events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
       <observers>
         <Company_Module_Model_Observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Company_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>switchStore</method>
         </Company_Module_Model_Observer>
       </observers>
     </controller_action_predispatch>
   </events>
 </global>
```

In Observer.php I've written script to check device type and based on result I set the store. Code snippet is as follows

```
if($handheldDevice) {
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('mobile_view'); //It's my store view code
}
```

It's switching store fine. I can set different home page for each store and categories too. All cms pages, cart page also seem good. But when I click a category, I'm getting oops error page. Why is it so? (Category is active in admin).

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the category url with the normal Magento way to change storeviews: www.url.com/?___store=storecode.

If that also fails, it is certainly a configuration issue and not something related to yourmodule.